# How do I get a new license for gDEBugger after the 1 free year?

Tags: graphics-programming, debugging

I downloaded the gDEBugger from [gremedy](http://www.gremedy.com/) over a year ago, with their one year free license.  The license has since expired and their site says that I'll be presented with the option for 1 year free license the first time I run it after install. This doesn't happen when re-installing, it just tells me the license has expired. How do I get a new license? I use this regularly for debugging shader problems and performance testing my game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the C:\ProgramData\GraphicRemedy directory, run gDEBugger again and ask for a new temporary license.

If you are using linux, check the .gremedy directory and remove the existing license file.

Comment: Thanks Meli. This seems like it will work for people who want to stick with the older non-AMD version.

Comment: I actually ended up doing this because the new version doesn't have as nice of shader source tools like showing compile errors.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

As of December 2012, Gremedy has released a version of their software with the license mechanism disabled. It's available for download [here](http://www.gremedy.com/download.php).

> Version 5.8.1  Changed: Licensing mechanism disabled, it is no longer
>   needed to acquire a free license to run gDEBugger.

---

The gDEBugger from gremedy appears to have been abandoned. Their forums have been down for a while and the last release on their site was December 16, 2010 with version 5.8.

AMD now hosts AMD gDEBugger. [Their website](http://developer.amd.com/tools/gDEBugger/Pages/default.aspx) has a release from April 20, 2012 with version 6.2 (as of this writing). The system requirements now list 'The latest AMD Catalyst driver'. The program will still operate without an AMD card, however kernel debugging will be disabled.